# Running sbt tasks from commandline without plugin.sbt

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

How to run an **sbt** build with task from a plugin that is not defined in `plugins.sbt`?

In maven it's as easy as:
`mvn groupId:artifactId:1.2.3:goal`

e.g. `mvn org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:7.1.1:check`

In sbt I get:

```
$ sbt net.vonbuchholtz:sbt-dependency-check:4.1.0:check
...
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: net (similar: set, new, inspect)
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: net (similar: test, name, run)
[error] net.vonbuchholtz:sbt-dependency-check:4.1.0:check
[error]    ^
```

Comment: If your project don't have some plugin you can add it globally for all your projects, exactly for cases like this. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to have plugin added to sbt to be able to call it.

If you don't want to add it to the project you can add it globally:

```
// Put things into
//   ~/.sbt/1.0/plugins/plugins.sbt
// Actually, you can name the file differently as long as it's in
//   ~/.sbt/1.0/plugins/
// and ends with .sbt, sbt will load all files ending with .sbt
// from there. 
addSbtPlugin("net.vonbuchholtz" % "sbt-dependency-check" % "4.1.0")
```

Alternatively, you can define some globally ignored file in `.gitignore` (assuming you are using git and don't want to accidentally commit things).

```
// ~/.gitconfig
[core]
     excludesfile = ~/.gitignore_global
```

```
// ~/.gitignore_global
local.sbt
```

Then you can add all you want there e.g. `local.sbt` - you will be able to add some ad hoc changes to you repo and don't worry that they will be commited upstream.

As yet another option, you can put these plugin configs into some file e.g. `~/.extra_plugins.sbt` and add them with a command line:

```
// ~/extra_plugins.sbt
addSbtPlugin("net.vonbuchholtz" % "sbt-dependency-check" % "4.1.0")
```

```
sbt --addPluginSbtFile="~/extra_plugins.sbt" dependencyCheck
```

As far as I can tell you cannot skip the step when you are creating the `.sbt` file. At best you could auto-generate it and populate it with a script:

```
// something like this
local tmp_sbt=`mktemp`
echo 'addSbtPlugin("net.vonbuchholtz" % "sbt-dependency-check" % "4.1.0")' >> "$tmp_sbt"
sbt --addPluginSbtFile="$tmp_sbt" dependencyCheck
rm "$tmp_sbt"
```